# Add Trendline if none exists

Tags: excel, vba, charts, trendline

I have created the following code to format a chart. Now I only want to add a trendline if none exists yet.
How do I do this or where is my mistake?
I am sure that I am missing something obvious

```
Sub FormatChart_A()
   Dim serReihe As series
                    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("test_A").Chart
                        For Each serReihe In .SeriesCollection
                            If InStr(serReihe.Name, "value_A") > 0 Then
                                serReihe.ChartType = 65
                                serReihe.Border.Color = RGB(165, 79, 255)
                            ElseIf InStr(serReihe.Name, "value_B") > 0 Then
                                serReihe.ChartType = 65
                                serReihe.Border.Color = RGB(79, 225, 235)
                                .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
                            ElseIf .SeriesCollection(serReihe.Name, "value_B").Trendlines.Count = 0 Then
                                .SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add Type:=xlLinear, Name:="Trend Flächenleistung"
                            End If
                        Next serReihe
                    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect that `.SeriesCollection(serReihe.Name, "value_B")` will return? `SeriesCollection` only takes one argument, and you already have the `Series` object in `serReihe`.

Comment: It is also unclear to me why you are iterating over the series, but addressing the `.AxisGroup` and `.TrendLines` specifically for series 2 and 1, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the name of the series, you can simply use:

```
If .SeriesCollection("Value_B").Trendlines.Count = 0 Then
    .SeriesCollection("Value_B").Trendlines.Add Type:=xlLinear, Name:="Trend Flächenleistung"
End If
```

There is no need to iterate through the series to do this.

Comment: I don't know why, but the code doesn't work. To answer your questions: I address the axes as this is only part of the overall code I am using. I am suppressing the multiple selection with my main code and then formatting a custom chart back to the original formatting
I have copied many parts from the internet so I didn't want to just publish it again

Comment: Without the rest of the code it will be hard for anyone to figure out what's going wrong... The above code works fine on my test workbook, but I don't have your code or your data.